# How do install gcc 4.4 and g++ 4.4 on Fedora 27

Tags: gcc, g++, fedora-27

I have Fedora 27 and will compile a applicationh with gcc4.4 and g++4.4.

But i can not install this version with 
yum or with update-alternatives

Can you help me

Comment: That compiler version is not available for Fedora 27. The least amount of work for you, by order of many days, is to install an older Fedora version that contains this compiler version - or port your code so it works with the newer gcc version that comes with Fedora 27. Note that providing assistence with software installation is quite off-topic here, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Oh thanks so lot, I install now the Fedora 18.

Comment: It looks gcc 4.4.7 is in the latest centos 6.9 release